# The argument type 'Html' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I have the below code that I want to be able to share HTML formated data to other applications. However, **Share.share( Html(data: note))** brings an error since it expects a string. So, how can I convert an **HTM widget** to a string

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
class ReadNote extends StatelessWidget {
   String note;
   ReadNote({Key? key,required this.note}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(note);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Note'),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share), onPressed: () {
                final RenderObject? box = context.findRenderObject();
                Share.share( Html(data: note),
                    subject:"Sharing a note"
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child:Html(data: note)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is the full error

```
Error: The argument type 'Html' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
 - 'Html' is from 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_html-2.1.2/lib/flutter_html.dart').
                Share.share( Html(data: note),
```

Comment: Can you add full error message to question and line in code where you are causing this error?

Comment: The full error is appended.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that share method of Share class need String type parameter as a first position parameter.

But in your case, you pass the Html class instance to String type place.

```
  String htmlToString(String html) {
    final parsedHtml = parse(html);
    final String parsedString = = parse(parsedHtml.body.text).documentElement.text;

    return parsedString;
  }

...
   Share.share(_parseHtmlString(note), subject: 'Look what I made!');
...
```

Comment: I changed code. Please check again

Comment: this is working but it jus removed all the tags leaving the text unformatted